# eclipse no repository found (nexus proxy)

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus

In our work, developers have several times encountered the problem that when developing in the Eclipse environment, some proxy repositories become unavailable. In this regard, it becomes necessary to view their source URLs.

Please advise how developers in the nexus interface can find out the source urls of the proxy repository

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the Nexus version?

Comment: hi,  Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.4-03

Comment: http://nexus02.ooo.ru/content/repositories/Jetty9415 / -
source proxy repositories address is the correct link ?